# What "bad" things may happen (and why) if a Terminal Emulator and the Shell running in it are using different TERM types?

Tags: shell, terminal, putty, pty

For example, in PuTTY's configuration I set terminal type to `xterm-256color` but after SSH login I change it with `export TERM=linux` in the shell.

I know it works quite well for most time. Just want to understand what the inconsistency (between PuTTY and the remote Shell) actually implies from the technical perspective.

Comment: When TERM doesn't correspond to the actual terminal, programs that manipulate the screen won't be able to do that correctly. In your case, it could be that both `xterm-256color` and `linux` correspond to the terminal, but one of the two might offer fewer features than the other (e.g., for sake of argument, `linux` might only support 16 colours).

Comment: I think of it as analogous to the browser `User-Agent` request header: a vague, indirect hint to the receiver about the capabilities of the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TERM` variable is used to look up the capabilities of the terminal/emulator and the right codes to send for terminal control functions like changing colors, moving the cursor around, or clearing the screen.

In theory, the terminal type identified by the `TERM` variable will be exactly described by the terminal type descriptions located in `/usr/share/terminfo/` directory tree. In practice, the terminal emulator might have bugs causing its behavior to deviate from the type specification.

(The terminal type specifications themselves might also contain errors, but this is very old technology, with most of the bugs worked out long ago.)

As an analogy, the terminals will speak their own language(s) natively; the applications don't usually speak it directly, but use the *terminfo* database as a set of dictionaries/phrasebooks to communicate with terminals. The TERM environment variable will determine which dictionary/phrasebook to use.

If the TERM value is only slightly wrong, i.e. indicating a terminal type that is not exactly correct but sufficiently similar, things might mostly work, perhaps with just reduced functionality like having just 16 colors available instead of 256, as berndbausch said in the question comments.

You might see some garbage characters on your screen if a program attempts to use a feature that does not exist in your actual terminal type. If the error is the other way (i.e. the terminal type description does not include a feature your terminal actually has) then the program will just behave as if your terminal did not have that feature available.

But if the TERM value is totally wrong (indicating a totally unrelated terminal type), then things like clearing the screen, and other basic functionality will not be available and any attempt to use them will most likely produce garbage characters on your screen because the program is sending terminal control codes in a format the terminal emulator does not actually recognize. In this state, use of e.g. normal text editors (instead of old-school line-oriented editors like classic `ex` or `ed`) will be very difficult or impossible until the TERM value is corrected.

If the TERM value is completely missing, most programs that need it will assume the default value of `dumb`: a very ancient terminal that has extremely limited capabilities and might even have a printer instead of a screen. In this situation, you won't get the garbage characters, but just like with a totally incorrect TERM setting, the use of regular text editors or anything that produces a text-based full-screen display (drop-down or pop-over menus on top of existing view, for example) on the terminal window will be impossible.

For an example of use of a very old terminal, see CuriousMarc's video on YouTube:
https://youtu.be/2XLZ4Z8LpEE?t=501

Note that in the video, there actually was a specific TERM value `tty33` readily available in Linux, although CuriousMarc had `agetty` set it for him instead of directly assigning the `TERM` variable. The `dumb` value might be even more bare-bones than that!

Since this TERM type stuff was designed to cover a lot of older technology that did not necessarily have anything that would be usable as a type detection mechanism, there was initially no provisions for terminal type auto-detection at all.

For hard-wired serial terminals, the system administrator was supposed to configure the correct terminal type when they were adding a `getty` process for each serial port connected to a new terminal. For modem lines, the system might be configured to *ask the user* for the correct terminal type in `/etc/profile` or similar, unless the session was detected to be a non-interactive one.

There were some developments for terminal type auto-detection, but these were not reliable for all circumstances (because there was just too many different old terminal types) and so auto-detection remained an optional feature that could be enabled if the administrator felt it was worth it for them.

Later, when network-protocol-based remote access methods were being developed, one of the features added was the ability to automatically pass some extra information from the client to the remote host while connecting, TERM value probably among the first of them. "And there was a great rejoicing."

Comment: The auto-detection of window size is [part of the ssh protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4254#section-6.7) and of the tty interface (`SIGWINCH`, `TIOCGWINSZ`), and messing with the `TERM` envvar does not affect it. Yes, there are are special terminal escapes to directly ask the terminal about [its size](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps;Ps;Ps-t:Ps-=-1-8.2068), but they're generally not used, and even if supported, may be disabled by default.

Comment: full screen display may be impossible or just limited. At least `less` seems to fall back on a stupider mode if the `TERM` settings are off.

Comment: putty supports more than one terminal types (xterm, xterm-256color, ...). does that mean putty must have its own copy of these terminal type's *terminfo* database?

Comment: Edited. And clarified that on "full-screen display" I meant things like drop-down or pop-over menus for example.

Comment: @pynexj No, *terminfo* database is a machine-readable description on how to control a terminal, and it's located at the remote end. PuTTY *implements* all those terminal types, which takes more code than just having the terminal type descriptions at hand... but since those terminal types are somewhat similar, it would be more correct to say that PuTTY implements a set of features that is a sum of those terminal types' feature sets, and some of the subsets can be switchable.

Comment: PuTTY implements a small fraction of the available terminal types (just a few percent).  For most of those, PuTTY will do interesting things, not what OP intended.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I meant, PuTTY implements a set of features that is the sum of *those terminal types PuTTY claims to support* (those pynexj referred to), not the sum of all terminal types in existence.But having a terminfo description of them built in PuTTY is not a requirement, just like if you are a native speaker of language X, you don't need a phrasebook for that language to communicate in that language.

Answer (score 1):

PuTTY is only using that "terminal type" configuration option for the default `TERM` environment variable used by *PuTTY-the-ssh-client* when [requesting a pseudo-terminal on the remote-server](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-6.2).

Using that setting to determine the terminal sequences that *PuTTY-the-terminal-emulator* recognizes and how it interprets them would be quite dumb -- and in fact, PuTTY is [not doing such a thing](https://github.com/github/putty/search?q=CONF_termtype).

Comment: putty has to know how to interpret the terminal's escape sequences otherwise it cannot display the right colors, right?

Comment: iterm2's [doc](https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-profiles-terminal.html) says "If `xterm-256color` is selected and your system is missing the terminfo file, you will be prompted to install it when you open a new session." sounds like iterm2 requires the terminfo file to work properly otherwise it does not know how to interpret the escape sequences.

Comment: @pynexj putty has that knowledge built in. And I suspect that you're misreading the iterm2's documentation -- iterm2 doesn't care about the terminfo database, but the ncurses programs which run in it do, and will not be able to use 256 colors without it. Anyways, I'll remove the hedging from my answer -- after looking at the source, I'm pretty sure that `CONF_termtype` does not change its behaviour, but only the terminal type it reports itself as in the ssh/telnet/rlogin protocols.

Comment: The best course of action is probably to set the terminal type to `putty` or `putty-256color`, but you may have problems with curses apps on old systems which lack an entry for it in their terminfo or termcap database.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, while PuTTY's behavior is *similar* to the terminals for which those descriptions were written, it is neither a superset nor exact match for either.

There are a few issues when the terminal description does not match the terminal:

- if it lists a capability that the terminal implements differently, then applications will behave incorrectly
- if it omits a capability that the terminal implements, applications will ignore the feature
- if it lists a capability that the terminal does not implement, again, applications will behave incorrectly.

The recommended terminal descriptions for PuTTY are ["putty"](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_Pu_T_T_Y) and ["putty-256color"](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-putty-256color).  Using infocmp to show the differences serves to illustrate:

- Generally speaking, terminals which support 256-colors also support 8 colors.  There are differences within each group.  PuTTY lacks the ability to customize the color palette (so its 256-color support is incomplete), but it does partly support the feature:

```
    comparing putty to putty-256color.
        comparing booleans.
        ccc: T:F.
        comparing numbers.
        colors: 8, 256.
        pairs: 64, 65536.
        comparing strings.
        initc: '\E]P%p1%x%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%02x%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%02x%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%02x', NULL.
        setab: '\E[4%p1%dm', '\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t4%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;%p1%d%;m'.
        setaf: '\E[3%p1%dm', '\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;%p1%d%;m'.
```

Comparing "putty" against [linux](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-linux) shows that each has features that the other lacks, and that for common features some are different:

```
comparing putty to linux.
    comparing booleans.
    bw: T:F.
    eo: F:T.
    hs: T:F.
    AX: F:T.
    XT: T:F.
    comparing numbers.
    ncv: 22, 18.
    comparing strings.
    acsc: '``aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~', '++\,\,--..00``aaffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~'.
    cbt: '\E[Z', NULL.
    civis: '\E[?25l', '\E[?25l\E[?1c'.
    cnorm: '\E[?25h', '\E[?25h\E[?0c'.
    cud1: '\ED', '\n'.
    cuu1: '\EM', '\E[A'.
    cvvis: NULL, '\E[?25h\E[?8c'.
    dim: NULL, '\E[2m'.
    dispc: '%?%p1%{8}%=%t\E%%G\342\227\230\E%%@%e%p1%{10}%=%t\E%%G\342\227\231\E%%@%e%p1%{12}%=%t\E%%G\342\231\0\E%%@%e%p1%{13}%=%t\E%%G\342\231\252\E%%@%e%p1%{14}%=%t\E%%G\342\231\253\E%%@%e%p1%{15}%=%t\E%%G\342\230\274\E%%@%e%p1%{27}%=%t\E%%G\342\206\220\E%%@%e%p1%{155}%=%t\E%%G\340\202\242\E%%@%e%p1%c%;', NULL.
    dsl: '\E]0;\007', NULL.
    enacs: '\E(B\E)0', '\E)0'.
    flash: '\E[?5h$<100/>\E[?5l', '\E[?5h$\E[?5l'.
    fsl: '^G', NULL.
    ich: NULL, '\E[%p1%d@'.
    ich1: NULL, '\E[@'.
    indn: '\E[%p1%dS', NULL.
    is2: '\E7\E[r\E[m\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l\E[4l\E8\E>\E]R', NULL.
    ka1: '\EOq', NULL.
    ka3: '\EOs', NULL.
    kb2: '\EOr', '\E[G'.
    kc1: '\EOp', NULL.
    kc3: '\EOn', NULL.
    kcub1: '\EOD', '\E[D'.
    kcud1: '\EOB', '\E[B'.
    kcuf1: '\EOC', '\E[C'.
    kcuu1: '\EOA', '\E[A'.
    kent: '\EOM', NULL.
    kf0: '\EOy', NULL.
    kf1: '\E[11~', '\E[[A'.
    kf2: '\E[12~', '\E[[B'.
    kf3: '\E[13~', '\E[[C'.
    kf4: '\E[14~', '\E[[D'.
    kf5: '\E[15~', '\E[[E'.
    kind: '\E[B', NULL.
    kmous: '\E[', NULL.
    rs1: NULL, '\Ec\E]R'.
    rs2: '\E<\E["p\E[50;6"p\Ec\E[?3l\E]R\E[?1000l', NULL.
    s0ds: '\E[10m', NULL.
    s1ds: '\E[11m', NULL.
    s2ds: '\E[12m', NULL.
    sgr: '\E[0%?%p1%p6%|%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;m%?%p9%t\016%e\017%;', '\E[0;10%?%p1%t;7%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p3%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p5%t;2%;%?%p6%t;1%;m%?%p9%t\016%e\017%;'.
    smcup: '\E[?47h', NULL.
    smkx: '\E[?1h\E=', NULL.
    tsl: '\E]0;', NULL.
    TS: '\E]0;', NULL.
    XM: '\E[?1006;1000%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;', NULL.
    kp1: '\EOq', NULL.
    kp2: '\EOr', NULL.
    kp3: '\EOs', NULL.
    kp4: '\EOt', NULL.
    kp5: '\EOu', NULL.
    kp6: '\EOv', NULL.
    kp7: '\EOw', NULL.
    kp8: '\EOx', NULL.
    kp9: '\EOy', NULL.
    kpADD: '\EOl', NULL.
    kpDIV: '\EOQ', NULL.
    kpDOT: '\EOn', NULL.
    kpMUL: '\EOR', NULL.
    kpNUM: '\EOP', NULL.
    kpSUB: '\EOS', NULL.
    kpZRO: '\EOp', NULL.
    xm: '\E[<%i%p3%d;%p1%d;%p2%d;%?%p4%tM%em%;', NULL.
```

Comparing "putty-256color" and [xterm-256color](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-256color) shows that PuTTY does not (for example) implement most of the function-key combinations that xterm provides:

```
comparing putty-256color to xterm-256color.
    comparing booleans.
    OTbs: F:T.
    bw: T:F.
    ccc: F:T.
    hs: T:F.
    km: F:T.
    mc5i: F:T.
    npc: F:T.
    xon: T:F.
    AX: F:T.
    comparing numbers.
    cols: NULL, 80.
    lines: NULL, 24.
    ncv: 22, NULL.
    U8: 1, NULL.
    comparing strings.
    acsc: '``aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~', '``aaffggiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~'.
    clear: '\E[H\E[J', '\E[H\E[2J'.
    cnorm: '\E[?25h', '\E[?12l\E[?25h'.
    cud1: '\ED', '\n'.
    cuu1: '\EM', '\E[A'.
    cvvis: NULL, '\E[?12;25h'.
    dim: NULL, '\E[2m'.
    dispc: '%?%p1%{8}%=%t\E%%G\342\227\230\E%%@%e%p1%{10}%=%t\E%%G\342\227\231\E%%@%e%p1%{12}%=%t\E%%G\342\231\0\E%%@%e%p1%{13}%=%t\E%%G\342\231\252\E%%@%e%p1%{14}%=%t\E%%G\342\231\253\E%%@%e%p1%{15}%=%t\E%%G\342\230\274\E%%@%e%p1%{27}%=%t\E%%G\342\206\220\E%%@%e%p1%{155}%=%t\E%%G\340\202\242\E%%@%e%p1%c%;', NULL.
    dsl: '\E]0;\007', NULL.
    enacs: '\E(B\E)0', NULL.
    fsl: '^G', NULL.
    ich: NULL, '\E[%p1%d@'.
    initc: NULL, '\E]4;%p1%d;rgb\:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\E\\'.
    invis: NULL, '\E[8m'.
    is2: '\E7\E[r\E[m\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l\E[4l\E8\E>\E]R', '\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>'.
    kDC: NULL, '\E[3;2~'.
    kEND: NULL, '\E[1;2F'.
    kHOM: NULL, '\E[1;2H'.
    kIC: NULL, '\E[2;2~'.
    kLFT: NULL, '\E[1;2D'.
    kNXT: NULL, '\E[6;2~'.
    kPRV: NULL, '\E[5;2~'.
    kRIT: NULL, '\E[1;2C'.
    ka1: '\EOq', '\EOw'.
    ka3: '\EOs', '\EOy'.
    kb2: '\EOr', '\EOu'.
    kc1: '\EOp', '\EOq'.
    kc3: '\EOn', '\EOs'.
    kend: '\E[4~', '\EOF'.
    kf0: '\EOy', NULL.
    kf1: '\E[11~', '\EOP'.
    kf13: '\E[25~', '\E[1;2P'.
    kf14: '\E[26~', '\E[1;2Q'.
    kf15: '\E[28~', '\E[1;2R'.
    kf16: '\E[29~', '\E[1;2S'.
    kf17: '\E[31~', '\E[15;2~'.
    kf18: '\E[32~', '\E[17;2~'.
    kf19: '\E[33~', '\E[18;2~'.
    kf2: '\E[12~', '\EOQ'.
    kf20: '\E[34~', '\E[19;2~'.
    kf21: NULL, '\E[20;2~'.
    kf22: NULL, '\E[21;2~'.
    kf23: NULL, '\E[23;2~'.
    kf24: NULL, '\E[24;2~'.
    kf25: NULL, '\E[1;5P'.
    kf26: NULL, '\E[1;5Q'.
    kf27: NULL, '\E[1;5R'.
    kf28: NULL, '\E[1;5S'.
    kf29: NULL, '\E[15;5~'.
    kf3: '\E[13~', '\EOR'.
    kf30: NULL, '\E[17;5~'.
    kf31: NULL, '\E[18;5~'.
    kf32: NULL, '\E[19;5~'.
    kf33: NULL, '\E[20;5~'.
    kf34: NULL, '\E[21;5~'.
    kf35: NULL, '\E[23;5~'.
    kf36: NULL, '\E[24;5~'.
    kf37: NULL, '\E[1;6P'.
    kf38: NULL, '\E[1;6Q'.
    kf39: NULL, '\E[1;6R'.
    kf4: '\E[14~', '\EOS'.
    kf40: NULL, '\E[1;6S'.
    kf41: NULL, '\E[15;6~'.
    kf42: NULL, '\E[17;6~'.
    kf43: NULL, '\E[18;6~'.
    kf44: NULL, '\E[19;6~'.
    kf45: NULL, '\E[20;6~'.
    kf46: NULL, '\E[21;6~'.
    kf47: NULL, '\E[23;6~'.
    kf48: NULL, '\E[24;6~'.
    kf49: NULL, '\E[1;3P'.
    kf50: NULL, '\E[1;3Q'.
    kf51: NULL, '\E[1;3R'.
    kf52: NULL, '\E[1;3S'.
    kf53: NULL, '\E[15;3~'.
    kf54: NULL, '\E[17;3~'.
    kf55: NULL, '\E[18;3~'.
    kf56: NULL, '\E[19;3~'.
    kf57: NULL, '\E[20;3~'.
    kf58: NULL, '\E[21;3~'.
    kf59: NULL, '\E[23;3~'.
    kf60: NULL, '\E[24;3~'.
    kf61: NULL, '\E[1;4P'.
    kf62: NULL, '\E[1;4Q'.
    kf63: NULL, '\E[1;4R'.
    khome: '\E[1~', '\EOH'.
    kind: '\E[B', '\E[1;2B'.
    kri: '\E[A', '\E[1;2A'.
    kspd: '^Z', NULL.
    mc0: NULL, '\E[i'.
    mc4: NULL, '\E[4i'.
    mc5: NULL, '\E[5i'.
    meml: NULL, '\El'.
    memu: NULL, '\Em'.
    mgc: NULL, '\E[?69l'.
    nel: '\r\n', NULL.
    oc: '\E]R', '\E]104\007'.
    ritm: NULL, '\E[23m'.
    rmacs: '^O', '\E(B'.
    rmcup: '\E[2J\E[?47l', '\E[?1049l\E[23;0;0t'.
    rmm: NULL, '\E[?1034l'.
    rmpch: '\E[10m', NULL.
    rs1: NULL, '\Ec\E]104\007'.
    rs2: '\E'.
    s0ds: '\E[10m', NULL.
    s1ds: '\E[11m', NULL.
    s2ds: '\E[12m', NULL.
    sgr: '\E[0%?%p1%p6%|%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;m%?%p9%t\016%e\017%;', '%?%p9%t\E(0%e\E(B%;\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p5%t;2%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p7%t;8%;m'.
    sgr0: '\E[m\017', '\E(B\E[m'.
    sitm: NULL, '\E[3m'.
    smacs: '^N', '\E(0'.
    smcup: '\E[?47h', '\E[?1049h\E[22;0;0t'.
    smglr: NULL, '\E[?69h\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%ds'.
    smm: NULL, '\E[?1034h'.
    smpch: '\E[11m', NULL.
    tsl: '\E]0;', NULL.
    u8: '\E[?6c', '\E[?%[;0123456789]c'.
    Cr: NULL, '\E]112\007'.
    Cs: NULL, '\E]12;%p1%s\007'.
    Ms: NULL, '\E]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\007'.
    Se: NULL, '\E[2 q'.
    Ss: NULL, '\E[%p1%d q'.
    TS: '\E]0;', NULL.
    kDC3: NULL, '\E[3;3~'.
    kDC4: NULL, '\E[3;4~'.
    kDC5: NULL, '\E[3;5~'.
    kDC6: NULL, '\E[3;6~'.
    kDC7: NULL, '\E[3;7~'.
    kDN: NULL, '\E[1;2B'.
    kDN3: NULL, '\E[1;3B'.
    kDN4: NULL, '\E[1;4B'.
    kDN5: NULL, '\E[1;5B'.
    kDN6: NULL, '\E[1;6B'.
    kDN7: NULL, '\E[1;7B'.
    kEND3: NULL, '\E[1;3F'.
    kEND4: NULL, '\E[1;4F'.
    kEND5: NULL, '\E[1;5F'.
    kEND6: NULL, '\E[1;6F'.
    kEND7: NULL, '\E[1;7F'.
    kHOM3: NULL, '\E[1;3H'.
    kHOM4: NULL, '\E[1;4H'.
    kHOM5: NULL, '\E[1;5H'.
    kHOM6: NULL, '\E[1;6H'.
    kHOM7: NULL, '\E[1;7H'.
    kIC3: NULL, '\E[2;3~'.
    kIC4: NULL, '\E[2;4~'.
    kIC5: NULL, '\E[2;5~'.
    kIC6: NULL, '\E[2;6~'.
    kIC7: NULL, '\E[2;7~'.
    kLFT3: NULL, '\E[1;3D'.
    kLFT4: NULL, '\E[1;4D'.
    kLFT5: NULL, '\E[1;5D'.
    kLFT6: NULL, '\E[1;6D'.
    kLFT7: NULL, '\E[1;7D'.
    kNXT3: NULL, '\E[6;3~'.
    kNXT4: NULL, '\E[6;4~'.
    kNXT5: NULL, '\E[6;5~'.
    kNXT6: NULL, '\E[6;6~'.
    kNXT7: NULL, '\E[6;7~'.
    kPRV3: NULL, '\E[5;3~'.
    kPRV4: NULL, '\E[5;4~'.
    kPRV5: NULL, '\E[5;5~'.
    kPRV6: NULL, '\E[5;6~'.
    kPRV7: NULL, '\E[5;7~'.
    kRIT3: NULL, '\E[1;3C'.
    kRIT4: NULL, '\E[1;4C'.
    kRIT5: NULL, '\E[1;5C'.
    kRIT6: NULL, '\E[1;6C'.
    kRIT7: NULL, '\E[1;7C'.
    kUP: NULL, '\E[1;2A'.
    kUP3: NULL, '\E[1;3A'.
    kUP4: NULL, '\E[1;4A'.
    kUP5: NULL, '\E[1;5A'.
    kUP6: NULL, '\E[1;6A'.
    kUP7: NULL, '\E[1;7A'.
    ka2: NULL, '\EOx'.
    kb1: NULL, '\EOt'.
    kb3: NULL, '\EOv'.
    kc2: NULL, '\EOr'.
    kp1: '\EOq', NULL.
    kp2: '\EOr', NULL.
    kp3: '\EOs', NULL.
    kp4: '\EOt', NULL.
    kp5: '\EOu', '\EOE'.
    kp6: '\EOv', NULL.
    kp7: '\EOw', NULL.
    kp8: '\EOx', NULL.
    kp9: '\EOy', NULL.
    kpADD: '\EOl', '\EOk'.
    kpCMA: NULL, '\EOl'.
    kpDIV: '\EOQ', '\EOo'.
    kpMUL: '\EOR', '\EOj'.
    kpNUM: '\EOP', NULL.
    kpSUB: '\EOS', '\EOm'.
    rmxx: NULL, '\E[29m'.
    smxx: NULL, '\E[9m'.
```

Comment: "neither a superset nor exact match for either" it almost sounds like a terminfo entry which would describe a covering *subset* of the current terminal emulators (xterm, rxvt, vte, putty, linux, mlterm, etc) would be a good idea, after all

Comment: People have suggested this, but no one's proposed a credible "covering subset".